# Open Inbuilt Map Intent For Driving Direction

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to open an `inbuilt google map intent` to show route between two place without open a `complete action dialog, which asked for Browser and Map` .

I tried this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+PreferenceData.getLatitude(HotelInfomation.this)+","+PreferenceData.getLongitude(HotelInfomation.this)+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it opens a dialog asking Complete Action Using Browser or map . I don't want that Dialog .

Comment: *You* may not want that dialog. Some of your users will -- after all, they may prefer to use a different mapping app. Your users are perfectly capable of checking the "Make this the default for now on for this action" in the chooser if they get tired of the dialog.

Comment: @CommonsWare , Thanks for your valuable suggestion . I will do what you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
without open a complete action dialog, which asked for Browser and Map
```

In this case you need to tell android which application you want to use to display map.

Here you go

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+PreferenceData.getLatitude(HotelInfomation.this)+","+PreferenceData.getLongitude(HotelInfomation.this)+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This will not be reliable. For starters, Google Maps is not on every device. Second, all Google needs to do is refactor their app, or change the `exported` flag on that activity, and this code breaks. In fact, since there are many versions of Google Maps installed on Android devices, it is entirely possible that this does not even work today across all of them. Never hard-code in class and package names for apps that are not your own.

Comment: @VipulShah: Well, the "workaround" is to simply allow the user to use the chooser. Or, use a `geo:` URL instead of an `http:` URL, though that still will bring up a chooser if the user has multiple mapping apps installed (e.g., Google Maps and OsmAnd).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
                                    + Data.map_latitude + ","
                                    + Data.map_longitude + "+&daddr="
                                    + Data.infoLatitude + ","
                                    + Data.infoLogitute + ""));
```